# ES6 modules: How to automatically re-export all types in the current directory from index.js?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, flowtype, commonjs

I have lots of code like this scattered around `index.js` files throughout my React Native project:

```
import Restaurant from './Restaurant';
import Store from './Store';
import Vineyard from './Vineyard';
import Wine from './Wine';

export {
    Restaurant,
    Store,
    Vineyard,
    Wine
};
```

It's very repetitive and tedious to write out. Is there a way I can automatically re-export all of the other files in the current working directory from `index.js`? (**note** I'm also using [Flow](https://flow.org/) in my project so any solution should preserve the type information it can infer.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
export * from './Restaurant';
export * from './Store';
```

By using the above syntax, you can access all exported properties from each component and export them directly.

This is a common pattern when you grouping all `Actions` in each individual `Action` file inside `index.js` and exporting them directly. You can have a look at the  [github repo](https://github.com/isaaclem/Jobs/blob/master/actions/index.js)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this pattern if you'd like:

```
export { default } from './Comp'
export { default as CompHeader } from './CompHeader'
export { default as CompContent } from './CompContent'

// Usage
import Comp, { CompHeader, CompContent } from './component/Comp'
```